# Pandoc font family not changing

Tags: pdftex, luatex, pdf, pandoc

I tried to set the font family to Source Sans Pro, but pandoc gives me the following error:

```
pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable
fonts.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox
```

I have sourcesanspro installed via miktex console and set the yaml header as follows:

```
---
geometry: margin=2cm
papersize: a4paper
toc: true
fontenc: T1
fontfamily: sourcesanspro  
fontfamilyoptions: sfdefault
---
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess your TeX installation lacks the CM-Super fonts. Are you using MiKTeX?

Comment: Yes, I use miktex: I tried installing cm-super, but I could not see a difference. Maybe I was using the fontfamily etc, settings wrong.
Could you provide an example how to do it correctly for cm-super?

Comment: I know nothing about Pandoc.

Comment: You should mention the version of Pandoc you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The `sourcesanspro` package uses an old version of the fonts; it's better to use the latest version of Source Sans Pro installed on your system, and use it directly with `fontspec`:

```
pandoc -o test.pdf --pdf-engine=lualatex << EOT

---
mainfont: Source Sans Pro
---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

EOT
```

Answer (score 1):

`sfdefault` is not an option provided by the `sourcesanspro` package.

[image: Source Sans Pro options]

## My settings

- Tex Live 2018
- sourcesanspro v2.6 (Dec 3, 2016)
- Pandoc v.2.7.1

## Procedure

Content of `input.md` (`T1` is the default option for `fontenc`):

```
---
geometry: margin=2cm
papersize: a4paper
toc: true
fontfamily: sourcesanspro
fontfamilyoptions: default
---

# Introduction

This is a sample sentence.
```

Command:

```
pandoc -t latex -o output.pdf input.md
```

Output:

[image: Sample Output]